# How to reuse test code in imported package?

Tags: unit-testing, go, architecture, integration-testing

Here is my directory hierarchy:

```
/
|-- main.go // package main, an HTTP server which accepts request and calls C/U APIs in pkg1 to finish certain task
|-- main_test.go // wants to call veryfyTaskNumber in pkg1_test
|-- pkg1 // package pkg1, CRUD APIs with Retrieve&Delete unexported for safety
    |-- pkg1_test.go // contains a function verifyTaskNumber(*testing.T, taskName string, expectedNo int) which calls internal Retrieve function in pkg1
```

I have some utility functions for tests only in `pkg1_test.go`. `main.go` imports `pkg1`. Now I want to use these functions in my `main_test.go`. After searching I found two possible solutions, but both of them have some drawbacks:

- Move these functions into `pkg1.go`. However these functions might be contained in binaries generated by `go build`.
- Move these functions into a separate `testutility` package, then import it in `*_test.go` manually. The problem is that these functions use some internal methods in `pkg1`.

So I was wondering whether there is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: Usually you don't want to explicitly use un-exported functions in test code. I would consider this a code smell and explore other ways to organize your code. If you give more details someone might be able to help you out more.

Comment: I'd also add that you don't _have_ to call the test function from main_test.go. You could just let go call it for you if you name it properly. (i.e. with "Test" at the front)
https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Testing

Answer (score 8):

If you use this function in `*_test.go` file throughout the project it's a good idea to move it to a utils package and import this package in your `*_test.go`. Moreover since this util package is used only for testing purposes I suggest to save the output of the internal function of `pkg1` in a support file and load it when you call the support package's function which should use the private function of `pkg1`.

Comment: A package with the utilities for testing is the best way here.

Comment: A package with test utility will help everyone else *except* the package where those relevant testing sources actually exist, due to cycling import issue. i.e. "pkg1" has a bunch of structs that you want to test, and a "util" package has some testing utilities which depend on this package. This "util" can be used everywhere else *except* "pkg1" due to cyclic import.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear when I wrote the first answer but I really don't see the point to create a utils package for testing without a proper isolation for pkg1. We should have a little bit more of comprehation about how the pkg1 was developed and how the test function call the pkg1 function before discussing about the possible cycling import. If you have a similar problem and you want an opinion feel free to ask :)